# How to insert annotation on the very top facet of ggplot in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, annotations, facet-wrap

I would like to have the `annotation` on the very first `facet` of the following `ggplot`. right now, the code draws `annotation` on all `facets`. Anyway forward would be appreciate.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "1 month"),
                  Ob = runif(60,1,5), L95 =runif(60, 0,4), U95 = runif(60,2,7), Sim = runif(60,1,5)) %>% 
      pivot_longer(names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value", -Date)

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Value))+
  facet_wrap(~ Variable, scales = "free_y", nrow = 4)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date("2004-12-01"),color = "red", size = 1.30)+
  annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("2002-01-01"), y = 3, label = "Calibration")+
  annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("2005-06-01"), y = 3, label = "Validation")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `geom_text`. Create a separate dataframe for plotting.

```
library(ggplot2)

text_data <- data.frame(x = as.Date(c("2002-01-01", "2005-06-01")), 
                        y = 3.5, Variable = sort(unique(DF$Variable))[1], 
                        label = c("Calibration", "Validation"))

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Value))+
  facet_wrap(~ Variable, scales = "free_y", nrow = 4)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date("2004-12-01"),color = "red", size = 1.30) + 
  geom_text(data = text_data, aes(x, y, label = label), color = 'blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ronak, can you please look into this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970528/annotation-on-only-the-first-facet-of-ggplot-in-r.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this wrapping data coordinates for the value on top of facets using `geom_text()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
#Code
ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Value,group=Variable))+
  facet_wrap(~ Variable, scales = "free_y", nrow = 4)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date("2004-12-01"),color = "red", size = 1.30)+
  geom_text(data=data.frame(Variable='L95',Date=as.Date("2002-01-01"),
                            label="Calibration",Value=max(DF$Value)),
            aes(y=Value,label=label))+
  geom_text(data=data.frame(Variable='L95',Date=as.Date("2005-06-01"),
                            label="Validation",Value=max(DF$Value)),
            aes(y=Value,label=label))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks @Duck, i want the `annotation` on the first `facet` not on all `facets`. right now the code draws `annotation` on all four `facets`. The `calibration` and `validation` text should be displayed on the very top `facet`.

Comment: @Hydro Hi dear. Deeply sorry for misunderstanding the task. I thought you wanted labels on top of each facet. Now, I have updated the post. Hoping that can be useful for you!